# Accessing the Salesforce API for the first time... using python

Tags: rest-api, python

Really early days for me learning to use the API as well as Python.

The code below Authenticates and passes back the token correctly - but I have no idea how to pass the session ID in the code after... I get an "invalid session ID error".

I simply need help with getting the "get" to authenticate and execute a simple request successfully. Thank you!

```
import requests
    consumer_key = "xxxx"
    consumer_secret = "xxxx"
    username = "xxxx"
    password = "xxxx"
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': consumer_key,
        'client_secret': consumer_secret,
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    r = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
        headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        data=payload)
    print r.content
    r = requests.get("https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/wave")
    print r.text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to Set up [Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm):

*Once authenticated, every request must pass in the access_token value in the header. It cannot be passed as a request parameter.*

Parse for `access_token` in request.content. Then use it in Authorization header:

```
import json, requests
#...
body = json.loads(r.content)
token = body["access_token"]
url = body["instance_url"] + "/services/data/v36.0/limits"

r = requests.get(url, headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token});
print r.content
```

Comment: I'm getting an error : "    tokens = r["access_token"]
TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: my bad, content is a list of bytes, it should be loaded to json

Answer (score 3):

For now it is necessary additionally to have `security_token`.

You can get it in SalesForce, using `Lightning` Theme:

1. Click in the top right corner your `profile icon` -> `Settings`;
2. In the tree select `My Personal Information` -> `Reset My Security Token`;
3. Click `Reset Security Token`;
4. Check your email for a new token.

In order to get `client_id` and `client_secret` (also known as `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`) in SalesForce, using `Lightning` Theme it is necessary to:

1. Click Gear Icon in the top right corner (next to Profile Icon) -> Setup;
2. In the tree select `PLATFORM TOOLS` -> `Apps` -> `App Manager`;
3. Click `New Connected App` in the top right corner;
4. Fill in all required fields;
5. Tick `Enable OAuth Settings` + enter any `Callback URL` + select needed Scopes;
6. Click `Save` at the bottom, then `Continue`;
7. On the new page you will see `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret` fields.

---

```
import requests

email = user@gmail.com
password = 'your_password'
security_token = 'admlnlkrsl'

client_id = 'Asdmlansdkjaduqoenaqonq234234'
client_secret = 'sdqlasdasmdpfk2093jdsajdiom'

your_instance = 'https://your_company.lightning.force.com'

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'username': email,
    'password': password+security_token
}

request_token_url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"

r = requests.post(
    request_token_url,
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, data=payload)

body = r.json()
token = body['access_token']

url = your_instance + "/services/data/v45.0"
r = requests.get(url, headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
print('response:', r.json())
```

[SalesForce API Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm)

[SalesForce EndPoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm)