# First time accessing the salesforce api **token**

Tags: python, access, refresh-token

Hello according to this link :

[Accessing the Salesforce API for the first time... using python](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120318/accessing-the-salesforce-api-for-the-first-time-using-python)

I have executed a python and got the following

> C:\ProcesosCTM\Sales_Force>call python
> C:\ProcesosCTM\Sales_Force\token.py
> b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication
> failure"}' [{"message":"Session expired or
> invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Can you help me with it ?

this is my python file and i think there must be anything lost with the token.

import requests

```
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
payload = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': consumer_key,
        'client_secret': consumer_secret,
        'username': username,
        'password': password
           }
r = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
data=payload)
print (r.content)
r = requests.get("https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/wave")
print (r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting "authentication failure" you may need to include your **security token** with the password.

```
...............
...............
password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
security_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
...............
...............
'password': password+security_token 
...................
...................
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- Do you have a user account setup in SalesForce for this username/password?

  - `"grant_type": "password"` uses user credentials to login
  - Other grant types use different endpoint URLs
- Do you have IP restrictions turned on?

  - Then you need to send your password concatenated with your security token: [password][security token] as the value of `password`
- Is this a sandbox instance of SalesForce?

  - If so, you need to use this endpoint: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token where `login` is replaced with `test`
- Still not working?

  - Check that the client ID and secret match the values in SalesForce for your Connected App

Once you successfully authenticate, you need to use the instance_url you get back for requests.  In your example it's `ap2.salesforce.com` but will be different for different instances:

```
r = requests.get("https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/wave")
print (r.text)
```